# $_SESSION data gets destroyed after Facebook Login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-oauth

I've implemented a method for users to add their Facebook accounts to their site account. It was working fine until I switched from stage domain to my production domain. (They're hosted on different servers)

I'm redirecting the user to the Login URL as below:

```
$params = array("redirect_uri" => SITE_URL . "settings/accounts");
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

In `SITE_URL . "settings/accounts"`, I check for $_GET["state"], and finish the integration. The problem with the production server is, the $_SESSION now only holds some gibberish (at least, to me) Facebook objects. The user data in $_SESSION is gone, so that I can't bind the facebook_id to his userID.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook returns $_SESSION / $_GET vars as a signed block, and you have to use the PHP SDK to extract them. Try something like this:

```
$facebook -> getSignedRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I missing something here?

Most likely you’re missing the fact that your session was not *destroyed*, but a **new** one has been created … check that, and if the case, fix the old *third party cookies* problem.